How to write insert query using CTE from another table in typeorm query builder
I'm trying to create an SQL query using typeorm's query builder but facing some issue with CTE express which will be the input query for the UPSERT statement
Below is the SQL query that I would like to convert to typeorm's query builder format:
WITH orders AS (
    SELECT
        bt.order_id AS ref_id,
        ANY_VALUE(bt."type") AS "type",
        SUM(bt.quantity) AS quantity,
    FROM broker_trade bt
    GROUP BY bt.order_id
)
INSERT INTO trade (ref_id, "type", quantity)
SELECT * FROM orders
ON CONFLICT (ref_id)
DO UPDATE SET quantity=EXCLUDED.quantity;

Can anyone please help me with this?
